# Replacing 0 kb files on the hard drive

Tags: windows, replace

Good day.

Situation: we recently created a new file server on Windows Server and copied a lot of files to it, some of which are 0 kb in size; there is a backup server on Windows Server, which stores the same files, but in the original size.

What steps can I take to replace only 0 kb files from one server to another? Is it possible to do this with the robocopy utility or do I need to use scripts?

I will be grateful a lot for your answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can force to overwrite them?

Comment: What happened to cause the 0kb files? How do you know the other files are good? Are there any other defining characteristics of the 0kb files that are different from the originals like modified date, etc? It’s not clear why you have a backup server but can only restore over the 0kb files? Typically I would say you use the robocopy command to just overwrite all files that do not match the backup copy. Or, you could overwrite all files that are older, etc. there’s just not enough detail here to come up with a plan. It is an unusual request and feels like we are missing important details.

Comment: If there was not a simpler way to do it, based on missing details, you could write a powershell script to build a list of 0kb files, then use that to build a list of source and destination file paths to copy with robocopy or with powershell.